# How to insert into a table several entries from a php along with static information

Tags: php, mysql, insert, associative-array

I have a form to be filled from a user. Please have a look at this link
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/danielestopponi.com/images/form.png

The only field to be filled is the quantity.

All the other fields are taken from a database which depends on the department the user has per attribute.

```
      $con = mysqli_connect($hostdb,$userdb,$passwdb,$dbTEST);
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Impossibile connettersi a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $sql_descr = "SELECT info.id_infostore_descr AS idinfo, info.supplier AS supplier, info.type AS type, info.descr AS descr, dg.descr AS dgroup, d.dept_descr AS dept\n" 
. "FROM infostore_descr AS info\n"
. "INNER JOIN dept_group AS dg ON info.infostore_dept_group = dg.id_dept_group\n"
. "INNER JOIN dept_assoc AS da ON dg.id_dept_group = da.id_dept_group\n"
. "INNER JOIN dept AS d ON d.id_dept = da.id_dept\n"
. "WHERE da.id_dept = " . $id_dept . "\n"
. "GROUP BY descr\n"
. "ORDER BY supplier AND type";
  $results_descr = mysqli_query($con, $sql_descr) or die(mysql_error());
  if (!$results_descr) {
    echo "Error: " . mysqli_error($con) . " - Contact the administrator";
  } else {
    $row_descr = mysqli_fetch_array($results_descr,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($results_descr);
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
```

Then I have the form

```
          <form name="infostore" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" role="form">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Insert information</legend>
          <table class="table">
            <tr>
              <th>Supplier</th>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Dept Group</th>
              <th>Dept Descr</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            while ($row_descr = mysqli_fetch_array($results_descr,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
              $array_sql_insert = array();
              echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row_descr['supplier'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row_descr['type'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row_descr['descr'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row_descr['dgroup'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row_descr['dept'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                echo '<div class="form-group">';
                  echo "<input class='form-control' type='number' name='qty[]' id='idqty' required placeholder='Insert Quantity' value='<?php echo $value; ?>'>";
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</td>';
              echo '</tr>';

            }
            ?>
          </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <hr></hr>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
              <label for="submit">Submit</label>
              <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="Invia" id="submit">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-7">
              <label for="reset">Reset</label>
              <input class="btn btn-danger" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" id="reset">
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

What i need is to INSERT INTO table "infostore" all the entries submitted by the user.
The user must fill all the row, but each user may have a different amount of row. Which row the user can see is decided by me with the SQL query you have seen above.

The problem is that the field it must be sent come from different source: associative array, Session and POST

I think I understood how i should do it but i'm completely lost because i dont understand how to put togheter the information.
I thought to create an associative array with the field i need which are:
$_SESSION['id_dept'], $row_descr['id_infostore_descr'], $_POST['qty']

Then I thought to do the SQL query

```
INSERT INTO infostore(id_dept,id_infostore_descr,qty) VALUE array[..string..]
```

where

```
array[($_SESSION['id_dept'], $row_descr['id_infostore_descr'], $_POST['qty']) , ($_SESSION['id_dept'], $row_descr['id_infostore_descr'], $_POST['qty']) ....and so on for each row submitted.]
```

I'm completely lost because i don't know how to put all togheter these different sources.

Answer (score 0):

I solved!!!

This is the trick that did the magic. If somebody can give advice if it could have been done better, You are welcome!

```
    <?php
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];

    //I create an array with all the value i have to upload and then transform it into a string
    $i=-1;
    $array_insert_string = array();
    mysqli_data_seek($results_descr,0);
    //I dont understand why if id dont do the data_seek qui above
    //the above while doesn't start from position 0, as if something make it moving forward
    while ($row_descr = mysqli_fetch_array($results_descr,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $i++;
      //I create the string and push each one into the array
      $string = "(" . $_SESSION['id_dept'] . ", " . $row_descr['idinfo'] . ", " . $qty[$i] . ")";
      array_push($array_insert_string, $string);
    }
    //I aggregate all the value of the array into one total string
    $string_total = implode(", ", $array_insert_string);

    //reset for the next while below
    mysqli_data_seek($results_descr,0);
  }

  // non serve la funzione clean_data poichè l'input è solo numerico
  // verifica il form e se tutte le condizioni sono rispettate
  // allora invia il form al database

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $con = mysqli_connect($hostdb,$userdb,$passwdb,$dbTEST);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Impossibile connettersi a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    // escape variables for security
    function escape($array) {
      global $con;
      return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $array);
    }
    //array_map consente di applicare una funzione a tutti gli elementi di un array
    //sicurezza superflua ma sempre meglio
    $qty = array_map("escape", $qty);
    if (!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO infostore (id_dept, id_infostore_descr, qty) VALUES " . $string_total)) {
      die ("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
  }
?>
```